# Wildcard in URL

Tags: wildcard

I download a file from a sharepoint and the script works fine, but I need to specify the file that I want to download. this one have an increment number at this end. I don't want to specify this one (as it not always the same) in my script.

I would like to replace this one by a wildcard like * but without success till now.  I'm a beginner in powershell :-(.

I hope that you can help me. 
The code used is:

```
$Username="Username"
$Password="pwd"
$FileURL="http://Sharepoint/folder1/folder2/filenameWEEK08.xlsx". 
$saveName ="C:\folder1\folder\filename.xlsx
$WebClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$WebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true; 
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
$WebClient.DownloadFile($FileURL, $saveName);
```

in this one I would like to replace WEEK08 by a * (or something like this)
Than you in advance for your help. 
patrick

Comment: How do you download the files? Can you share the code?

Comment: Please do not share such information in the comments. They are relevant to the question and should be given there

Comment: Also, please don't include potentially sensitive information such as usernames and passwords. Please delete your comment above?

Comment: answer deleted and code added in to the question. thanks